Broken symlinks on LXC mountpoints are not colored red in `ls`

My Ubuntu 22.04 runs in an LXC on Proxmox, its ls has no colors

I added an alias ls="ls --color=auto" and that colored folders/files differently

Proxmox uses ZFS as its filesystem which the LXC points to using  mountpoints

Broken symlinks in / of the LXC are colored red

However, broken symlinks on these mountpoints are not colored

Is there a way to color them?



What do you have mounted on these mountpoints? What filesystem? Does it support symlinks correctly?

proxmox is using zfs, mountpoints in LXC point directly to folders on the host zfs

Please include this info in the question, it is probably very relevant.
